# How to speed up iPhone DTMF signal dialing

Tags: iphone, dtmf

I am creating a dialing mobile app for iPhone using NSUrl function. The calling number consists of two parts - GSM service number and DTMF tones. For example, 810011111,46144443 .

Is it any possibility to make DTMF tones be dialed in similar way as the first part of dialed GSM number - quickly as one number ? Waiting for 8 digits takes too much time.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple developer support informed me that they haven't implemented no such function. But they kindly asked to explain them the need of the function and maybe they will implement it in the future.